# Validating that a passed in value can be made into a date

Tags: javascript, validation, types

I have a textbox that a user is suppose to enter a date of the form mm/dd/yyyy into. I am trying to make sure that this is the case and they not pass in a string. Since I am using new Date() in the below code I can understand that startDate/endDate are Dates even if they are invalid... So basically I'm searching for the correct way to go about doing this validation

```
  function calculate() {
    var start = document.getElementById("start").value;
    var end = document.getElementById("end").value;
    var startDate = new Date(Date.parse(start));
    var endDate = new Date(Date.parse(end));
    var daysBetween = parseInt((endDate - startDate)/(24*3600*1000));
    var er = document.getElementById("errorResult");

    if(!(startDate instanceof Date) || !(endDate instanceof Date)) {
        er.innerHTML = "Dates must be of the form mm/dd/yyyy";
        return;
    } else if (endDate<startDate) {
        er.innerHTML = "End date must be after start date!";
        return;
    } else {
        er.innerHTML = "";
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't answer your question directly, but if you have the option I suggest using moment.js if you are doing much date manipulation/formatting/validating: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/is-valid/

Comment: Insisting on two digit values for day and month is annoying, you should accept 4/5/2013 as well as 04/05/2013.

Comment: I agree I was planning on this but was just asking the question in general to get me started

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try this

```
function isValidDate(date)
{
    var matches = /^(\d{2})[-\/\.](\d{2})[-\/\.](\d{4})$/.exec(date);
    if (matches == null) return false;
    var d = matches[2], m = matches[1], y = matches[3];
    var newDate = new Date(y, m, d);
    return newDate.getDate() == d && newDate.getMonth() == m && newDate.getFullYear() == y;
}
```

In your function, you can check

```
var start = document.getElementById("start").value;
var end = document.getElementById("end").value;
if ( isValidDate( start ) && isValidDate( end ) )
{
    // valid
}
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/hMeZ2/1/)

Comment: Note that the OP is using the peculiar US month/day/year format, your code assumes day/month/year. Also note that 5/4/2013 is a "valid" date in both systems, but represents a different date, and you might want to include "." as a separator. Finally, to validate the date, you only need to test any two values (e.g. date and month), not all three. But it doesn't hurt. :-)

Comment: @RobG, thanks a lot for pointing me out the date format and for the tips :-)

Answer (score 1):

Use a regex

```
if (!inputDate.match(/^\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}$/)) {
  er.innerHTML = "Dates must be of the form mm/dd/yyyy";
  return;
}
```